# Emitting on upstream flow inside onSubscription is not collected - despite what documentation says

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

The documentation for `SharedFlow<T>.onSubscription` says: (emphasis mine)

> Returns a flow that invokes the given action after this shared flow starts to be collected (after the subscription is registered).
> The action is called before any value is emitted from the upstream flow to this subscription but after the subscription is established. **It is guaranteed that all emissions to the upstream flow that happen inside or immediately after this onSubscription action will be collected by this subscription.**
> The receiver of the action is FlowCollector, so onSubscription can emit additional elements.

However, when emitting on an upstream flow inside the `onSubscription` does not make the subscription collect this if we're in a shared flow that was created with `started = SharingStarted.Lazily`. See examples below.

---

SharingStarted.Lazily:

```
suspend fun main() {
    coroutineScope {
        val upstream = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()
        upstream.shareIn(
            scope = this,
            started = SharingStarted.Lazily,
        ).onSubscription {
            println("subscription")
            upstream.emit(42)
        }.collect {
            println("value $it")
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
subscription
```

---

SharingStarted.Eagerly:

```
suspend fun main() {
    coroutineScope {
        val upstream = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()
        upstream.shareIn(
            scope = this,
            started = SharingStarted.Eagerly,
        ).onSubscription {
            println("subscription")
            upstream.emit(42)
        }.collect {
            println("value $it")
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
subscription
value 42
```

---

I am aware that I can do `emit(42)` instead of `upstream.emit(42)`, but I want to emit a value on `upstream`.

I have tried wrapping my head around why this happens and what makes the `onSubscription` seem incorrect when using `SharingStarted.Lazily`, and when trying to explain it to others they don't seem to entirely understand it (and quite frankly neither do I apparently).

We have been looking at the code to see what happens in `.collect`, `.collectLatest`, `.shareIn` with the different `SharingCommand` operators etc. but we haven't entirely grasped why this happens.

Can anyone explain in details what is going on here, why is it apparently not guaranteed that all emissions to the upstream flow that happen inside or immediately after this onSubscription action will be collected by this subscription when using `SharingStarted.Lazily`? Preferably with concrete examples from the Flow implementation code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have two shared flows in each example, AND you're running your code in very restrictive dispatcher.

Your structure looks something like this:

```
upstream       : MutableSharedFlow
shareIn        : ReadonlySharedFlow  (backed by a new instance of MutableSharedFlow)
onSubscription : SubscribedSharedFlow
```

And the entire issue lies within this [block of code](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/7a87eabcbd8a34d61490eb3e41033b24a5320918/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/flow/operators/Share.kt#L218) in sharing logic:

```kotlin
            started === SharingStarted.Lazily -> {
                // start collecting on the first subscriber - wait for it first
                shared.subscriptionCount.first { it > 0 }
                upstream.collect(shared)
            }
```

Your flow for sample 1 looks something like this:

0. you declare `shareIn` which launches an internal `launchSharing` job - it's scheduled to execute when dispatcher allows it
1. start to `collect` your transformed `shareIn` flow
2. `onSubscription` collects from `shareIn`
3. `shareIn` "allocates slot", which increments its internal subscriber count
4. `shareIn` checks that collector is a `SubscribedSharedFlow`, executes its block
5. you emit straight to `upstream`: it is discarded without suspension because `upstream` has no subscribers
6. now `shareIn` suspends waiting for value from `upstream`
7. only here `launchSharing` job finally has a chance to run; it passes subscription count check and starts collecting `upstream`
8. everything is suspended until value is emitted into `upstream`

And sample 2 (with Eagerly sharing) is different like this:

0:  you declare `shareIn` which launches an internal `launchSharing` job - it immediately starts collecting from `upstream` because it's  started UNDISPATCHED (runs until suspension point disregarding dispatcher)

5: emit to `upstream` succeeds because it has subscribers

7: `shareIn` receives value from `upstream`